# How to populate checkbox with data from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have been trying to populate a list of checkboxes which values and names are retrieved from MySQL as well. I believe I need to match two iD's together to be able to mark it as checked but I am not sure at the moment.

```
$boardsiD = $pClass->checkedBoards();

foreach($pClass->retrieveBoards() as $data)
{
    $boardiD    =   $data['boardiD'];
    $boardName  =   $data['boardName'];

    if($boardiD == $boardsiD) ------------------ 1 ---------------------
    {
        $checked = 'checked="1"';
    }

    echo '
        <li><input '.$checked.' type="checkbox" value="'.$boardiD.'">'.$boardName.'</li>
    ';
}
```

Where the dashes with the number one in the middle is, I am there checking if the board id's are the same and if so then the `checked="1"` is applied. But it does not seem to be working.

The following is the output for the $boardsiD; These are the checkboxes that have been checekd in the database; saved the ids which is what I am trying to match against the `$boardiD = $data['boardiD']` which is the whole list of id's(about 30 id's).

```
Array (
        [0] => Array
                    ([board_iD] => 106468047379795203)
        [1] => Array
                    ([board_iD] => 286119451265381250)
        [2] => Array
                    ([board_iD] => 136234026166934321)
        [3] => Array
                    ([board_iD] => 468022654964640361)
        [4] => Array
                    ([board_iD] => 409757334785529893)
        [5] => Array
                    ([board_iD] => 409757334785575605)
        [6] => Array
                    ([board_iD] => 490681390589888313)
        )
```

I'm not sure if I can use preg_match for this or if I even should, I tried but it did not work very well, any ideas why the following does not work?

Comment: Sidenote: If you want it to be checked, you'd do `$checked = 'checked';` if that's your intention. Unless you want your checked value to appear as `<input checked="1"`

Comment: The above is correct fred, thank you. I want the box input box to be set to 1(checked="1") if the id matches with any that is retrieved from MySQL. That is my goal.

Comment: No sir, that wasn't it. I just appreciated you taking your time to help another human being out with a problem.

Comment: Ok, just curious. It's a little late here, so am having a bit of trouble concentrating and finding a solution. I should get some sleep.

Comment: I understand, I'm in brazil it's pretty late as well, just trying to get this sorted before I get to bed too.

Comment: I'm going to take a shot at this. Can you try `if($boardiD == $boardName)` --- are you trying to match what matches for `boardiD` and `boardName`?

Comment: No, I am trying to match two numbers together, if it is then it should return checked="1"; (checked="1" or checked="checked" is the same thing). The boardiD(below the foreach) against the boardsiD(outside the foreach).

Comment: What about `foreach($boardsiD->retrieveBoards() as $data)` since you're already assigning a variable to it `$boardsiD` - It's hard for me to say without seeing what the other 2 functions look like, or for someone else who will visit your question. Am unsure of the `retrieveBoards()` function, that's why.

Comment: This makes it much clearer.. http://pastebin.com/acFYqE0A . retrieveBoards = "SELECT * FROM table" and checkedBoards = "SELECT board_iD from table"

Comment: Sorry, I can't get my head around it. I tried.

Comment: the array you have echo'd is `$boardID`?

Comment: You probably could make use of a `WHERE` clause too, straight in your query.

Comment: Oh wow, I forgot about the WHERE clause completely, no idea why.. I'll give that a try.

Comment: There you go ;-) that should simplify things.

Comment: There's also `in_array()` that could be of added use.

Comment: Apparently also array_intersect(), but nothing have worked so far. Either way, I'll think of something. Thank you for your support, will keep trying.

Comment: You're welcome. Keep me posted. Cheers (am off to Lah-Lah Land).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checked="1" is invalid HTML. The correct Syntax for HTML4 would be

```
<input type="checkbox" value="someValue" checked>
```

or for HTML5

```
<input type="checkbox" value="someValue" checked="checked" />
```

---

To check if your $boardID is a value of $boardsID you can do the following:

```
$checked = '';

for($i = 0; !$checked && $i < sizeof($boardsID); $i++)
  if($boardID == $boardsID[$i]['board_iD'])
    $checked = 'checked="checked"';
```

Comment: @Fred-ii-, It was pretty much the same idea, it would pretty much be considered the same but I do have a question. Why didn't the foreach() work but the for() worked just fine, I though that foreach() also counted all that was returned from MySQL..

Comment: @iBrazilian2 This page will explain it better than I can http://ibmphp.blogspot.ca/2012/10/difference-between-foreach-and-for-loop.html --- Basically, `for` loop is to do something over and over again until the
task has been completed.

`foreach` works only on arrays. Even it will run the loop
until end of the array.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, be a dear and check this out. (When/if you have time) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796257/how-to-schedule-multiple-functions-to-be-executed-everyday/23796901?noredirect=1#23796901

Answer (score 1):

Your `$boardsiD` is a 2 dimentional array so lets convert it to a single dimentional array first.

```
$it =  new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($boardsiD));
$newBoardIDs = iterator_to_array($it, false);
```

then,

```
foreach($pClass->retrieveBoards() as $data)
{
    $boardiD    =   $data['boardiD'];
    $boardName  =   $data['boardName'];

    if(in_array($boardID,$newBoardIDs))
    {
        $checked = 'checked="1"';
    }

    echo '
        <li><input '.$checked.' type="checkbox" value="'.$boardiD.'">'.$boardName.'</li>
    ';
}
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: Did you go over the comments?